# FB.login() called before calling FB.init() - Facebook Canvas app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Am developing a facebook canvas app.

Url to my canvas app 
https://apps.facebook.com/bayern_app/

Everything works good but sometimes i got an error when i click the login button, ie, FB.login() called before calling FB.init(). Its very hard to replicate the issue, i got this one in some cases only, Am placing my login code at the end of the page, ie before closing body tag. I got this error fired in my ipad also.

I googled the issue, and got similar threads in stack, they all mention about all.js calling twice. But in my case am calling this only once in my page.

I also suspect about like button code in my page

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bayern3" data-width="100" 
data-layout="button" 
data-action="like" data-locale="de_DE" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false">
</div>
```

Login Facebook Javascript code

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
    FB._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");
    FB.init({ appId: {$appid},
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true});
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    }
    {literal}
            function loginurl(){

                FB.login(function(response) {

                    if (response.status === 'connected') {

                        location.href="game";


                    }
                    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized')
                    {

                       // FB.login();

                    } else
                    {

                       // FB.login();

                    }


                },{scope: 'email,user_hometown,user_mobile_phone,user_location,user_birthday,read_friendlists,publish_stream,xmpp_login'});
            }
    {/literal}
</script>
```

Please help me to find anything wrong in my code, Thanks in advance

Comment: Well that’ll happen if you click your button before the JS SDK has finished initializing. Workarounds would be to bind the handler that calls your login function to the login button dynamically inside the `fbAsyncInit` handler, and maybe not even display it until that event is fired.

Comment: thanks for you reply...i will check that way